# Triggers SQL no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Eu criei uma trigger chamada `trg_atualiza_produto_au`, ela vai ser acionada quando eu fizer uma alteração em um produto da tabela `produtos`. Eu queria saber, como eu faço para pegar apenas o produto que foi alterado e colocá-lo na tabela `produtos_atualizados`, pois quando eu altero algum produto acaba dando erro pois a trigger tenta pegar todos os produtos e eu só quero que ela pegue o que foi alterado.
Código das tabelas e triggers:

```
create table produtos(
    prod_codigo int not null auto_increment,
    prod_descricao varchar(25),
    prod_valor_decimal decimal(11,2),
    prod_status char(1),
    prod_estoque_minimo int,
    prod_qtd_estoque int,
    primary key(prod_codigo)
);
create table produtos_atualizados(
    prod_codigo int not null references produtos(prod_codigo),
    prod_qtd_anterior int,
    prod_qtd_atualizada int,
    prod_valor decimal(11,2)
);

delimiter $$
create trigger trg_atualiza_produto_au after update on produtos
for  each row
begin
    declare prod_codigo int;
    declare prod_qtd_estoque_atual int;
    declare prod_qtd_estoque_anterior int;
    declare prod_valor decimal(11,2);
    declare dia date;
    select new.prod_codigo,old.prod_qtd_estoque,new.prod_qtd_estoque,new.prod_valor_decimal
    into prod_codigo,prod_qtd_estoque_atual,prod_qtd_estoque_anterior,prod_valor
    from produtos;
    insert into produtos_atualizados(prod_codigo,prod_qtd_anterior,prod_qtd_atualizada,prod_valor)
    values(prod_codigo,prod_qtd_estoque_atual,prod_qtd_estoque_anterior,prod_valor);
    
end $$  
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta simplificar sua trigger da seguinte forma:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger trg_atualiza_produto_au after update on produtos
for  each row
begin
    insert into produtos_atualizados(prod_codigo,prod_qtd_anterior,prod_qtd_atualizada,prod_valor)
    values(new.prod_codigo,old.prod_qtd_estoque,new.prod_qtd_estoque,new.prod_valor_decimal);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

**Observação:**
Lembrando que é possível que seja realizado um `update` no código do produto `prod_codigo` que representa a chave primária da tabela `produtos`, caso isso ocorra, sua trigger não iria registrar qual era o código anterior, mas apenas o código atual **`new.prod_codigo`**.